# Using {{render}} to display a form and save a model instance from anywhere in the application

Tags: ember.js

I have a resource (Trip) and its routes - trips.index, trips.edit, trips.new. I would like to put a copy of the form in trips/new into application.hbs template so it appears on every page.

The form in trips/new route works but the one in application.hbs doesn't. I get the following errors when I submit the form:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('name', a) to
>   the 'content' property of object proxy
>   : its 'content' is
>   undefined.
>
> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('errorMessage',
>   You have to fill all the fields) to the 'content' property of object
>   proxy : its 'content' is
>   undefined.

I have the following code.

**application.hbs:**

```
...
{{render "trips/new"}}
...
{{outlet}}
...
```

**templates/trips/new.hbs:**

```
<form {{action "save" on="submit"}} role="form">

  <p class="text-danger">{{errorMessage}}</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Name</label>
    {{input class="form-control" value=name}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Country</label>
    {{input class="form-control" value=country}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Start Date</label>
    {{input class="form-control" value=startDate placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">End Date</label>
    {{input class="form-control" value=endDate placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"}}
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
  <button {{action "cancel"}} class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

**controllers/trips/base.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isValid: Ember.computed(
    'name',
    'country',
    function() {
      return !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('name')) &&
        !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('country'));
    }
  ),
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      if (this.get('isValid')) {
        var _this = this;
        this.get('model').save().then(function(trip) {
          _this.transitionToRoute('trips.show', trip);
        });
      } else {
        this.set('errorMessage', 'You have to fill all the fields');
      }
    },
    cancel: function() {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

**controllers/trips/new.js:**

```
import TripsBaseController from './base';

export default TripsBaseController.extend({
  actions: {
    cancel: function() {
      this.transitionToRoute('trips.index');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

**routes/trips/new.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('trip');
  },
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      return true;
    },
    cancel: function() {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Any idea how I can solve this? I'm about to try converting it into a View or component but I'm wondering if I can still use {{render}} and I'm missing something simple here.

I'm using ember-cli with ember 1.7.0 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.10.

I've also added a JS Bin here:
http://jsbin.com/zofive/edit

Comment: I might help if you provide JSBin

Comment: @saygun Thanks. I've added a JS Bin here: http://jsbin.com/zofive/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer - I needed to set the model using the Application Route, setupController and controllerFor.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('trips/new').set('model', this.store.createRecord('trip'));
  }
});
```

JS Bin (non-ES6): http://jsbin.com/zofive/13

Thanks to @locks, @abuiles and @xymbol.